# Вложенный список MaterialDrawer

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток. Использую библиотеку [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/). Требуется создать вложенный список в одном из пунктов меню, при нажатии на который этот список будет открываться. Может кто делал такое, подскажите пожалуйста. Спасибо. Инициализация:

```
final PrimaryDrawerItem item23 = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(23).withName(R.string.change_night_mode).withIcon(R.drawable.button_night_mode).withSelectable(false);
PrimaryDrawerItem item22 = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(22).withName(R.string.about_name).withSelectable(false).withIcon(R.drawable.about);

result = new DrawerBuilder()
        .withActivity(this)
        .withToolbar(toolbar)
        .withHeader(R.layout.drawer_header)
        .withTranslucentStatusBar(true)
        .withActionBarDrawerToggleAnimated(true)
        .addDrawerItems(
                item23,
                new DividerDrawerItem(),
                item22
        )
        .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                switch((int) drawerItem.getIdentifier()){
                    case 22: 
                        break;
                    case 23: 
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        })
        .build();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В сэмплах Майка есть [пример](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/app/DrawerActivity.java#L133) с айтемом, в котором раскрываются еще айтемы:

Коротко:

```
result = new DrawerBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withToolbar(toolbar)
            .addDrawerItems( new ExpandableDrawerItem().withName("Collapsable").withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_collection_case_play).withIdentifier(19).withSelectable(false).withSubItems(
                            new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("CollapsableItem").withLevel(2).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_8tracks).withIdentifier(2000)
                            new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("CollapsableItem 2").withLevel(2).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_8tracks).withIdentifier(2001))
            .build();
```

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо! Я бы там и не нашел.